# Indexing an array of chars - issue with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, indexing, char

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void getInput(char *password, int length)
{
    cout << "Enter password: ";
    cin >> *password;
}
int countCharacters(char* password)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (password[index] != "\0")
    {
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}
int main()
{
    char password[];
    getInput(password,7);
    cout << password;
    return 0;
}
```

Hi!
I'm trying two things here which I'm unable to do atm. I'm trying to create a char array with unspecified length in main, and I'm trying to count the number of words in the char array in the function countCharacters. But password[index] doesnt work.

EDIT: I'm doing a homework assignment, so I have to use cstrings only.
EDIT2: And I'm not allowed to use the "strlen"-function either.

Comment: There's simply no such thing as an array of unspecified length. It is possible to do with dynamically allocated memory, but you should just use `std::string` to encapsulate this.

Comment: What is the `length` parameter of `getInput` function? It's not used there.

Comment: The password length is 7. It is to be the limit of the password length. In my assignment I am to take the length as an argument in the getInput, and limit the input to 6 symbols + "\0". But how?

Answer (score 1):

At first replace

```
char password[];
```

by

```
char password[1000]; // Replace 1000 by any maximum limit you want
```

And then replace:

```
cin >> *password;
```

by

```
cin >> password;
```

Also instead of `"\0"` you should put `'\0'`

P.S. There is no char array with unspecified length in C++, you should use std::string instead(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/):

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string password;
    cin >> password;
    cout << password;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing a homework assignment, so I have to use cstrings only.